# Bootstrap 4 fixed-top not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having an issue with using 'fixed-top' with Bootstrap 4. It is working on my nav bar on the desktop. However, when using it when the navbar is collapsed it does not fix the navbar at the absolute top. When scrolling when it is collapsed the navbar will partially disappear before becoming fixed. About 50% of the navbar will disappear before becoming fixed at the top. When scrolling back up the navbar comes back into view. I'll link to a short video; https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lxr7Qw83Co_AYqaMsLOILglhqKjiQbF8/view

```
<div>
<nav id="mainNav" change-class class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent">

<!-- Logo -->
<a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#"><span class="logo-script">Some</span><span class="logo-block">Brand</span></a>

<!-- Toggler -->
<button class="navbar-dark navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navToggle" aria-controls="navToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<!-- Links -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navToggle">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white navbar-link-custom" href="#!/view1">SIGN IN</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white navbar-link-custom" href="#">REGISTER</a>
        </li>

        <!-- Logged In Links -->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="" class="nav-link text-white navbar-link-custom dropdown-toggle" type="text" id="profileDrop" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                WELCOME CHRIS
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px" aria-labelledby="profieDrop">
                <button class="dropdown-item-custom navbar-link-custom" type="button">My Profile</button>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <button class="dropdown-item-custom navbar-link-custom" type="button">Logout</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm also using AngularJS to add some color to the navbar on scroll but I'm pretty positive this has nothing to do with it, since it seems to be working fine by lg, and medium screens but the fixed top position is getting cut off on small screens.

I appreciate any feedback.

EDIT: It seems that this block of code that I use for the header is somehow creating part of this issue.. here is that code;

```
<div class="header">
<div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-12 my-auto">
        <h1 class="text-white text-center logo-block">
            NOT ALL <span class="logo-script">Brands</span> ARE CREATED EQUALLY
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.header {
background: #7F00FF;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #ff00ff 20%, #6705ff 200%);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to top, #ff00ff 20%, #6705ff 200%); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
height: 100vh;
```

}

The way this works.. the navbar is loaded, and under it I have the page which includes the code from above to load the header. When I remove the header block, the behavior still exists but the amount of movement is cut down dramatically.

Comment: You either come up with a way of inspecting code presented in a video or create a [mcve]. Assuming you need help, that is.

Comment: I posted the code in question? I cannot use JSFiddle to replicate because that works inside an iframe and I cannot get the screen size to collapse like it would on mobile.

Comment: Are you sure you know what "verifiable" means? It means your snippet has to have a "Run" button and the issue should be reproduced in the snippet contained in the question. Make sure you link every required resource from CDN to reproduce the issue. Also update the question with details ref devices/browsers it happens in. In principle, a question should not need comment discussions to be clear. **The code you posted is not sufficient to reproduce the described issue and therefore the cause cannot be determined.**

Answer (score 0):

I just did some testing with your code and found that your HTML snippet was invalid.

That *might* have been the reason for your issue because after fixing the error I did extensive testing and could not detect the behavior shown in your video. I also switched to Galaxy S5 (just for good measure because that's what you were using in your video) and in all cases, the navbar remains rock-solid at the top. None of the behavior shown in your video.

Here's the valid, working code I used (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full screen to test):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav id="mainNav" change-class class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent bg-primary">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#"><span class="logo-script">Some</span><span class="logo-block">Brand</span></a>

    <!-- Toggler -->
    <button class="navbar-dark navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navToggle" aria-controls="navToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navToggle">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white navbar-link-custom" href="#!/view1">SIGN IN</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white navbar-link-custom" href="#">REGISTER</a>
            </li>

            <!-- Logged In Links -->
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="" class="nav-link text-white navbar-link-custom dropdown-toggle" type="text" id="profileDrop" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                WELCOME CHRIS
            </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px" aria-labelledby="profieDrop">
                    <button class="dropdown-item-custom navbar-link-custom" type="button">My Profile</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <button class="dropdown-item-custom navbar-link-custom" type="button">Logout</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 90px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks unfortunately I'm still seeing the same behavior with your code when viewing on a small screen. I do appreciate the help and I understand this is difficult because reproducing the issue is a bit difficult. I'm just perplexed what could make simple CSS fixed-top not work correctly.

Please see my edited question, I've narrowed it down a bit..

Comment: OK, in this case, it's your local browser that does this. Not a general issue. But if you are still worried, you can add the following classes to the nav: `pt-4 pt-md-2` OR `pt-5 pt-md-2`. That will bump up the top padding for screens smaller than `md` and get it back down to the default 2 units from `md` screens onwards.